# VisualVM Memory sampling: Not available with websphere

Tags: java, websphere, visualvm

When I run visual VM and webSphere 7 on the same Server and same user "administrator"

I'm getting this error :
Memory sampling:
Not available. Cannot connect to target application. Make sure the application is running on a supported Java 6, Java 7 or Java 8.

Enviroment :

```
JVM 1.3.8
- JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.65-b04, mixed mode, sharing)  

Webspher 7
- JVM: IBM J9 VM (2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows 7 x86-32 jvmwi3260sr15-20131016_170922 (JITenabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20131016_170922
JIT - r9_20130920_46510ifx2
GC - GA24_Java6_SR15_20131016_1337_B170922)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your JVM start up parameters:

```
-agentlib:JPIBootLoader=JPIAgent:server=controlled;CGProf
```

In WebSphere this should be editable using the WebSphere Application Server administrative console, also known as the "IBM Integrated Solutions Console".

You'll need to make sure that the profiler library environment variables are set up correctly:

[Setting up environment variables to profile a (WebSphere) server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ws.ast.st.common.ui.doc%2Ftopics%2Frprofilingenvvar.html)

---

**Update**

If you get this error:

```
JVMJ9TI001E Agent library JPIBootLoader could not be opened. (The specified module could not be found.)
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9jvmti24(-3): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed
```

Follow this guide from IBM:

[Profile on server fails with JVMJ9TI001E error](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21319688)

Comment: after we try that  i found the below exception :

JVMJ9TI001E Agent library JPIBootLoader could not be opened (The specified module could not be found. )
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9jvmti24(-3): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed

Comment: You need to make sure that the profiler library environment variables are set up correctly: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ws.ast.st.common.ui.doc%2Ftopics%2Frprofilingenvvar.html